# Pandas vectorization: Cumulative sum based on JSON files

Tags: python, json, pandas, vectorization

I'm trying to sum a score based on values in a `DataFrame` and two `json`-files. I have a minimum example and a minimum solution, but this needs to be vectorized somehow because in the real-case there are over a million rows, and it took ~40min to run through 1% of the rows.

My `first.json`-file is:

```
{
    "variables" : {
        "var_1": {
            "values": [
                {
                    "lb": 1.0,
                    "b_cumul": 0.04
                },
                {
                    "lb": 3.0,
                    "b_cumul": 0.28
                }
            ]
        },
        "var_2": {
            "values": [
                {
                    "lb": 0,
                    "b_cumul": -0.09
                },
                {
                    "lb": 1,
                    "b_cumul": 0.14
                },
                {
                    "lb:": 4,
                    "b_cumul": 0.03
                }
            ]
        },
        "var_4": {
            "values": [
                {
                    "lb": "1",
                    "b_cumul": 0.06
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

My `second.json` file is:

```
{
    "variables" : {
        "var_1": {
            "values": [
                {
                    "lb": 1.0,
                    "b_cumul": -0.15
                },
                {
                    "lb": 2.0,
                    "b_cumul": 0.06
                },
                {
                    "lb": 4.0,
                    "b_cumul": 0.02
                },
                {
                    "lb": 5.0,
                    "b_cumul": 0.15
                }
            ]
        },
        "var_3": {
            "values": [
                {
                    "lb": 0.0,
                    "b_cumul": 0.12
                },
                {
                    "lb": 2.0,
                    "b_cumul": 0.25
                }
            ]
        },
        "var_6": {
            "values": [
                {
                    "lb": 0.0,
                    "b_cumul": -0.16
                },
                {
                    "lb": 1.0,
                    "b_cumul": -0.06
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

This is our initial dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
# setup initial test-data
usage = ['first', 'second', 'first', 'second', 'second', 'second', 'first']
var_1 = [-1, -1, 0, 1, 3, 8, 2]
var_2 = [1, 3, -1, 0, 9, 2, 1]
var_3 = [0, 1, 0, -1, -1, 42, 3]
df = pd.DataFrame({'usage': usage, 'var_1': var_1, 'var_2': var_2, 'var_3': var_3})
```

The variables `var_1`, `var_2`, `var_3` that are available in `df`, decides which variables we want to look at in the `json`-files. The scores should be cumulative sums retrieved from the `json`-files, depending on the values in `df`.

Looking at my first row, I have `(var_1=-1, var_2=1, var_3=0)`. Since `usage='first'` for this same row, I need to check in `first.json` what scores these variables correspond to. `var_3` does not exist in `first.json`, so this variable gives 0 score. `var_1=-1`, so this also gives 0 score. `var_2=1`, so here we need to look in `first.json` and get the scores for values corresponding to `<=1`, which in this case is `-0.09+0.14=0.05`. So we want to add this information in the dataframe by `df.loc[0, 'score_sum']=0+0-0.09+0.14`.

I have solved this with the code below, but as mentioned before this is very inefficient and does not work for a larger `df`.

```
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib.pyplot import plt
import json

# return score based on given value and score ranges
def calculate_score(value: Number, score_ranges: pd.DataFrame) -> Number:
    score_ranges.lb = pd.to_numeric(score_ranges.lb)
    if score_ranges.lb.min() > value:
        return 0
    score_sum = score_ranges.loc[(score_ranges.lb <= value), 'b_cumul'].sum()
    return score_sum

# read relevant data from json files
models = {key: [] for key in df['usage'].unique()}
for path in models:
    f = open(f"{path}.json")
    all_variables = json.load(f)['variables']
    relevant_variables = [x for x in df.columns if x in all_variables]
    for var in relevant_variables:
        models[path].append({var: all_variables[var]['values']})

# calculate scores
df['score_sum'] = np.nan
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    score = 0
    m = row['usage']
    for var in models[m]:
        var_name = list(var)[0]
        value = row[var_name] 
        if value == -1:
            score += 0
        elif value > -1:
            score += calculate_score(value, pd.DataFrame(var[var_name]))
    df.loc[index, 'score_sum'] = score
```

By running this code and then printing `df`, we notice that the first row has `score_sum=0.05` as intended. We `import seaborn, plt` at the top because we want to run `sns.distplot(df['score_sum'])` at the end and save the figure.

EDIT:
As requested, see below for a screenshot of the total resulting `DataFrame`. And just to clarify: For the second row, `usage='second'` which means we use `second.json`, however we don't have `var_2` in this `json` so `var_2=3` will just add `score_sum+=0`, but `var_3=1` will add `score_sum+=0.12`

[image]

Comment: for this example what would the df['score_sum'] values be for the rest of the initial dataframe from above?

Comment: @JonathanLeon see edited question for the resulting dataframe

Comment: cool. have you consider https://dask.org/ for multiprocessing across cores? or otherwise breaking up the dataframe to parallelize it?

Comment: hmm no not really. i was hoping that there was some way to vectorize this problem, maybe by storing the data from the json-files in another way, creating boolean masks or similar things.

Comment: i find this to be an interesting exercise. using apply() saves about 10% over iterrows, but still looking at alternatives. because you have to really evaluate each cell in every row, finding the right approach is tricky.

Comment: can you share a much larger data set? i'm wondering if some of the different iterations of doing this aren't looking as good because the data set is small. Are the json files much larger? is the test df much larger? if you can provide something additional maybe there's a better way other than multiprocessing (apply is better than iterrows so far is best solution)

Comment: @JonathanLeon hey sorry for not sharing a bigger dataset, but i added a working solution now using boolean masks to vectorize the dataframe instead of looping through it

Comment: No worries. I’ll look at your solution as I’m always looking to get better at this stuff. Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by looping through the `models` first as defined by `df['usage'].unique()` and will have an equivalent amount of `json`-files. Then we loop through each relevant variable in the `json`, then each incremental value for the given variable. We create masks inside each loop, and start by the lowest value since we want to cumulatively add the values.

```
df['new_scores'] = 0
for model in models:
    for var in models[model]:
        var_name = list(var)[0]
        json_values = pd.DataFrame(var[var_name])
        json_values = json_values.set_index('lb')
        for value in json_values.index:
            mask = (df[var_name] >= float(value)) & (df['usage'] == model)
            df.loc[mask, 'new_scores'] += json_values.loc[value, 'b_cumul']
```

When comparing the column from the old solution with the column from the new solution, the values are exactly the same. For the original dataframe of ~6M rows, it went from taking ~4h to iterate through 5% of the `dataframe`, to ~70s to run through the whole script.